# Android, Expandable List View, Remove child from single entry

Tags: android, expandablelistview

At the moment I'm running into issues with removing a UI element from an expandable List view. I'm using this in my getChildView()

```
View button = v.findViewById(R.id.moreInfoButton1);

if(button != null)
{
    ((ViewManager)button.getParent()).removeView(button);
}
```

Now I realize that I'm actually removing the element from the layout template, which means when expanding another element, the app crashes as it can't find the button. So is there a way of removing an element just from a single entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a flag in your data set and when you want to remove (hide) that element, set the flag of that element to `true` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` and in your `getView` method for child, when inflating your view, check for that flag and if it was `true` don't show that element!

example :

in your adapter :

```
...
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupposition, int childpostion, boolean isLastchild, View convertview,
        ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   if (data.get(groupposition).get(childposition).getFlag()) {
        yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   } else {
        yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
   ...
}
```

and add this field to your data :

```
public class ChildData {
   ...
   boolean flag;
   // getter and setter 
}
```

and when you want to toggle visibility of particular item :

```
yourExpandableListData.get(parentPosition).get(childPosition).setFlag(true);
yourExpandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you clarify further, an example perhaps or a link somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for that. It's hidden the button but I have noticed that the LinearLayout still keeps the space that the button would have been in. Is there a way of removing that extra space?

Comment: if you set visibility to `GONE` it won't take space but if you set that to `INVISIBLE` it'll take space on layout.

Comment: what are you using for data `data.get(..)`

Comment: It's the data set for adapter. For example a list of desired model for showing in expandableListView